# Sitecore & YouTube Integration module - errors during installation

Tags: youtube, sitecore, integration, marketplace, sitecore8.1

Has anyone used the [YouTube Integration module](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/modules/youtube_integration.aspx)? I'm trying to install it on Sitecore 8.1 but all the licence files seems to be corrupted and are erring (*Severe Error: Compressed data is invalid*)  - even if you just unzip the file using winrar/winzip.

Is there a similar module that could be used?

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: You could download the source for the module and build it yourself, then install the package. The module is not listed as being compatible with 8.1. Although if the zip file is corrupt, that wouldn't matter anyway.

Comment: I replied on the community forum, trying unpacking the zip and rebuilding it use the files form the source. Take a look at the [Youtube Video picker](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/Y/YouTube_Video_Picker_Field.aspx?sc_lang=en) module as an alternative.

Comment: hi @jammykam - i'll give a try to the YouTube Video picker thanks. By any chance have you downloaded and complied the code for the YouTube Integration Module? I've added in the Sitecore Reference cause it was missing but it keeps erroring with errors such as:Error 85 The type or namespace name 'Configuration' does not exist in the namespace 'Sitecore'

Comment: Just tried it and it worked fine. Did you change the target framework of the project to .Net 4.5.1?

Comment: yeah that worked but it clearly doesn't work at all on 8. abandoned it and gone ahead implementing the BrainJocks YouTube Video Picker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- unpacking the zip and rebuilding it use the files form the source.
- module does not work with Sitecore 8.1
- instead implementing [Youtube Video picker](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/Y/YouTube_Video_Picker_Field.aspx?sc_lang=en) - few tweaks to only show videos from my selected channel and loading the videos automatically